# Swift Realm filter on relationship object

Tags: swift2, realm

I am trying to carry out a filter on a List of Realm objects in the following way.

I have two objects Category and Company

```
class Category: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var isActive = true
    let companies = List<Company>() 
}

class Company: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
}
```

The category is sent from one Controller to another so that all the Companies in that Category can be shown

```
var category: Category!
var rlmCompanies: List<Company>?
```

So far so good, and from this I can display a list of companies. However, I am trying to add a switch bar to the top of the controller that will allow me to further filter the list of companies shown by whether they are active or not.

The code I am trying is on the lines of one of the following things I have tried

```
rlmCompanies = category.companies.filter("ANY isActive == true")
rlmCompanies = category.companies.filter("ANY companies.isActive == true")
rlmCompanies = category.companies.filter("companies.isActive == true")
rlmCompanies = rlmCompanies.filter("ANY companies.isActive == true")
rlmCompanies = self.rlmCompanies.filter("ANY companies.isActive == true")
```

All of these attempts give a similar error which is on the lines of:

```
No filter candidates produce the expected contextual result type List<Company>
```

I'm therefore running out of ideas. I can see that this is something to do with how the List has been initialised, but can't see what to do with it

Comment: Is `rlmCompanies` that you're assigning to a property on your controller class?

Comment: rlmCompanies is a variable within a controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed the code in the following ways

I changed the initialiser to be a Results object

```
var rlmCompanies: Results<Company>?
```

Then when I created the initial List I added a filter that returned all, and so returns a Result rather than a List

```
rlmCompanies = category.companies.filter("id <> 'somethingbogus' ")
```

I'd ideally have something like ANY rather than the id is not something bogus but can't find the syntax for that

Comment: `TRUEPREDICATE` is a predicate that will match every object.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because you're attempting to assign a `Results<T>` returned by `List.filter` to a variable of type `List<T>`. Your `rlmCompanies` instance variable should be of type `Results<Company>` instead.

Comment: Understood. So how do I declare a variable of type Results if it is part of the 1:Many that is identified in the Object. If I initialise with var rlmCompanies: Results<Company>?, and then assign it with category.companies I also get an error saying cannot assign type List to Results. How can I initialise and set the variables to use Results if it is part of the 1:M List as defined in the Object?

Comment: To clarify, do you sometimes want `rlmCompanies` to be filtered and other times not? If so, you can filter with a predicate of `TRUEPREDICATE` to get a `Results<T>` whose contents match the unfiltered `List<T>`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm after. ok thanks I'll research predicate. if you have some example code that would be great